# is there way to create component those HTML template replaces custom selector?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

i'm trying to teach myself angular2. I trying to build component "trigger-resize", which i want to render as :

```
<a class="hidden-xs" href="">
    <em class="fa fa-navicon"></em>
</a>
```

and NOT as:

```
<trigger-resize>

   <a class="hidden-xs" href="">
      <em class="fa fa-navicon"></em>
   </a>
</trigger-resize>
```

(i dont want custom selector to render)

In angular 1. i know it would be achieved by "replace:true" option, but is it possible to achieve it in angular2?

Kind Regards

Comment: What about using an attribute on `<a>` as selector instead of a tag like `<a trigger-resize class="hidden-xs"... >` and then in the component annotation `[trigger-resize]` as selector?

Comment: i dont want to make all "a" tags to become "trigger-resize", is that possible?

Comment: The way I explained it above all tags with the `trigger-resize` attribute become `trigger-resize`, but maybe you want to use a directive instead anyway. If you want to add resizable behavior a component is not the right way.

Comment: Thanks you very much, it is working!!!

Answer (score 5):

One way to do it is to use an attribute

```
<a triggerResize class="hidden-xs" href=""></a>
```

Which has a component like

```
@Component({
    selector : 'a[triggerResize]', //select all <a> tags with triggerResize attribute
    template : '<em class="fa fa-navicon"></em>'
})
```

CamelCase attributes are the proper syntax now for custom attributes in angular2

Answer (score 1):

You can use an attribute on `<a>` as selector instead of a tag like `<a trigger-resize class="hidden-xs"... >` and then in the component annotation use `[trigger-resize]` as selector.

```ts
<a trigger-resize class="hidden-xs" href="">
    <em class="fa fa-navicon"></em>
</a>
```

```ts
@Component({
    selector : '[triggerResize]'
    template : '<em class="fa fa-navicon"></em>'
})
```

This is also quite useable for other situations where specific tag names are required like `<li>` inside `<ul>` or `<tr>` inside `

```ts
<ul>
  <li myLi></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to the question is "no" – your custom element/selector will be in the HTML.  To quote the [Angular 1 to Angular 2 Upgrade Strategy doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xvBZoFuNq9hsgRhPPZOJC-Z48AHEbIBPlOCBTSD8m0Y/edit):

> Directives that replace their host element (replace: true directives in Angular 1) are not supported in Angular 2. In many cases these directives can be upgraded over to regular component directives.

That said, for your specific use case, as others have already mentioned, a component that uses an attribute selector would work.

See also

- [Remove the host HTML element selectors created by angular component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34280475/remove-the-host-html-element-selectors-created-by-angular-component)
- [Angular2 table rows as component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556277/angular2-table-rows-as-component)