# Angular2 Table Row component on Chrome displays in single column

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, angular, angular2-components

Versions in use:

- Angular 2.0.1
- angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.17

I have a page that is broken into 3 components. The page outline, a table which has it's own layout including rows, one of these rows contains a row component.
In IE the table displays fine, in Chrome all the data from the component row appears in the first column.

### main.html

```
<form>
     <div>Title Stuff etc.</div>
     <table-component [qlineModel]="QuoteLineModel"></table-component>
     <div>Other stuff</div>
</form>
```

### table.html

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ColA</th>
        <th>ColB</th>
        <th>Option</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <row-component *ngFor="let qlines of qlineModel" 
                            [qline]="qlines">
      </row-component>
      <tr>
         <td>Tot A</td>
         <td>Tot B</td>
         <td>Tot Opt</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

### row.html

```
<tr>
   <td>{{qline.A}}</td>
   <td>{{qline.B}}</td>
   <td>{{qline.C}}</td>
</tr>
```

IE gives me the output I would expect

```
       Title Stuff etc
   ColA |  ColB  | Col C
   100     200     300
   200     300     400
   ___________________
   300    500     700
       Other Stuff
```

However, Chrome gives me an output I don't expect

```
       Title Stuff etc
   ColA        |  ColB  | Col C
   100 200 300
   200 300 400
   _____       ______________
   300           500     700
       Other Stuff
```

I can get around it by putting table data into one component but a) defeats the object for me and b) I want to potentially print the table out so ideally would like to keep it as is.
I tried [Angular2 table rows as component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556277/angular2-table-rows-as-component) but kept getting NgFor only supports Iterables such as arrays

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a `<row-component>` inside a `<tbody>` because that is not a valid child for `<tbody>`.

You can change the selector of `RowComponent` to `[rowComponent]` and then use it like

```
<tr rowComponent *ngFor="let qlines of qlineModel" 
                        [qline]="qlines">
```

Comment: Perfect, I missed the [] around the selector, many thanks. Any reason why it was fine in IE?

Comment: Browsers just behave differently in such cases. I don't use IE much, but I know that IE removes the `<template>` tag inside tables while the standard and other browser allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Using a **selector: 'tr[row-component]'** in *RowComponent* would allow you to render

```
<table>
    <thead><!-- headers go here --></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr row-component *ngFor="let qlines of qlineModel" [qline]="qlines"></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is rendered correctly both on Chrome and IE.