# Angular 2 / 4 Recursive Table row component issue

Tags: angular, html-table, ngfor

Although the question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39964173/angular2-table-row-component-on-chrome-displays-in-single-column),the case here is different.

I have an array of items which contains single item as well as group of items, which in-turn may contain item and item-group.

And I want to display all of them as rows.

But the component shows all the data in single column.How to map them correctly

Logic I used

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Step No.</th>
            <th>Step Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <row-detail [data]="data"></row-detail>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Row Details

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let step of data">
    <ng-template *ngIf="step.type==='group'; then group; else normal"></ng-template>
    <ng-template #normal>
        <tr>
            <td>{{step.stepno}}</td>
            <td>{{step.stepName}}</td>
            <td>{{step.description}}</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #group>
        <row-detail [data]="step.data"></row-detail>
    </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

plnkr code

https://plnkr.co/edit/vsD0FOpkbrWdvlycpal9

Comment: Problem is that the `row-detail` elements get the inherited `display: table` style from the parent table. I don't think it's possible the way you like it. Especially not with the ancient table structure. Perhaps using a table created with `flex` will get what you want