# Angular 4 rendering child selector breaks the columns alignment into my table

Tags: angular

I am using angular 4 for my application, but I have an issue with angular selectors.
I've got a component table with a row child. 
Selector name for the child is "row".
I've called it from table component, like this:

```
<table class="table table--striped">
 <thead class="thead--dark">
  <tr>
   <th>Data versamento</th>
   <th>Importo</th>
   <th>ABI</th>
   <th>CAB</th>
   <th></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody class="form--light">
  <row [data]="item" *ngFor="let item of enpals_payments"></row>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Printing child selector into the html table, it breaks the columns alignment.

How do I force to skip row selector rendering?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `colspan`

```
<tbody class="form--light">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5"> 
      <row [data]="item" *ngFor="let item of enpals_payments"></row>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Comment: hi guys, I've found the right solution.. is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39964173/angular2-table-row-component-on-chrome-displays-in-single-column?rq=1