# angular2: strange result when using ngFor with a template that's supposed to represent a table row

Tags: html, angular

I created a stock-transaction template which is supposed to represent one row of a table.  When I add this to the table body of a table used in my app.component.html for some reason everything gets added to one column.  Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

```
my product-transaction.html:

    <td>{{stockTransaction?.Date | date}}</td>
    <td>{{stockTransaction?.TransactionType_Name}}</td>
    <td>{{stockTransaction?.SupplierMaster_Name}}</td>
    <td>{{stockTransaction?.Qty}}</td>

my stockTransaction.component.ts:

import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { StockTransactionModel } from '../../models/stock-transaction.model';


@Component({
  selector: '[stock-transaction]',
  templateUrl: './stock-transaction.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stock-transaction.component.css']
})
export class StockTransactionComponent implements OnInit {
@Input('stock-transaction') StockTransactionModel

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}


my app.component.ts:

import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { RestService } from "./services/rest.service";
import { ProductModel } from './models/product.model';
import { StockTransactionModel } from './models/stock-transaction.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
@ViewChild('focusInput') focusInput: ElementRef;
barcode: string;
barcodeForm: FormGroup;
product: ProductModel;
stockTransactions: Array<StockTransactionModel>;

    constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private restService: RestService){
        this.barcodeForm = fb.group({
            'barcode':['', Validators.required]
        }); }

submitBarcode(barcode: string) {    
    this.restService.getProduct(barcode)
    .subscribe(
    (res) => {      
        this.product = res;
        this.showStockTransactions(res.ProductCode);
    },
    (res) => {
        console.log("failure" + res);
    }
    );  
    this.barcodeForm.reset();
}

showStockTransactions(productCode: string) {    
    this.restService.getStockTransactions(productCode)
    .subscribe(
    (res) => {
        this.stockTransactions = res;
        console.log(this.stockTransactions);
    },  
    (res) => {
        console.log("failure " + res);
    }   
    );
}

 ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.focusInput.nativeElement.focus();
 }


}

my app.component.html:

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4">
<form [formGroup]="barcodeForm"  role="form" (ngSubmit)="submitBarcode(barcodeForm.value.barcode)" >
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="barcode" placeholder="Enter Barcode" [formControl]="barcodeForm.controls['barcode']"  name="barcode" #focusInput>         
    <button class="btn btn-submit btn-block" [disabled]="!barcodeForm.controls['barcode'].valid">Submit</button>
</form>

</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-2">
    <br /><br /><br /><br />
        <app-product [product]="product"></app-product>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<br /><br /><br />
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Supplier</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let stockTransaction of stockTransactions" [stock-transaction]="stockTransaction"></tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use attribute selector for your StockTransactionComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: '[stock-Transaction]',
  template: `
    <td>{{stockTransaction.Date | date}}</td>
    <td>{{stockTransaction.TransactionType_Name}}</td>
    <td>{{stockTransaction.SupplierMaster_Name}}</td>
    <td>{{stockTransaction.Qty}}</td>
  `
})
export class StockTransactionComponent {
  @Input('stock-Transaction') stockTransaction
}
```

And in parent view

```
<tr *ngFor="..." [stock-Transaction]="stockTransaction"></tr>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/l4ol5P5puCPiQ6KMpeNg?p=preview)**

See also

- [Angular2 table rows as component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556277/angular2-table-rows-as-component)

Comment: I now get the following error:    zone.js:388Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'stock-Transaction' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'. ("
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let stockTransaction of stockTransactions" [ERROR ->][stock-Transaction]="stockTransaction">
   
  </tr>
"): AppComponent@28:57 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error:

Comment: I've updated answer. You have to use correct attribute name

Comment: now all errors are gone but no rows are displayed in the table...  I can see the array of stockTransactions that come through from the server in chrome console but nothing gets displayed...  Any idea what else I can check?

Comment: Please provide plunker or github project. As you can see my plunker works well. I think you went wrong somewhere

Comment: Thanks for your effort...  I added all relevant code in my question

Comment: In StockTransactionComponent change `@Input('stock-transaction') StockTransactionModel;` to `@Input('stock-transaction') stockTransaction;` There is no `StockTransactionModel` variable in your template

Comment: that didn't make a difference...  shouldn't the @Input() be the type that's being input?  I know it's a stockTransaction but stockTransaction is a stockTransactiomModel

Comment: Then change your `product-transaction.html` `stockTransaction?.Date` to `stockTransactiomModel ?.Date`

Comment: this worked: @Input("stock-transaction") stockTransaction: StockTransactionModel;  Thanks again