# My own Angular 2 Table component - 2 way data binding

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I see that support for datatables in angular 2 is very poor. [DataTables](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started) does not work for me (known unresolved issue) so I thought that I will write something simple for myself. By the way I will learn something useful. I want to build my table in this way:

```
<my-table> 
    <my-table-row *ngFor="let row of rows">
         <my-table-col>{{row.col1}}</my-table-col>
         <my-table-col>{{row.col2}}</my-table-col>
    </my-table-row>
</my-table>
```

So I have created a component with simple filter input. Now, I would like to filter over my table. Angular should in some way assign data from my-table-col(s) to some variable (maybe 2way data binding will be useful?), then I would use some function triggered by keyup event to filter and data should update automatically but I do not know how to do that.

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-table',
    template: `
    <div style="width: 100%">
        <div style="float: left; height: 50px; width: 100%">
            Search: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterValue" style="height: 30px; border: 1px solid silver"/> {{filterValue}}
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 100%">
            <table>
                <ng-content></ng-content>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    `
})
export class MyTableComponent { 
    filterValue: string;
}  

@Component({
    selector: 'my-table-row',
    template: `
        <tr><ng-content></ng-content></tr>
    `
})
export class MyTableRowComponent { 
}   

@Component({
    selector: 'my-table-col',
    template: `
        <td><ng-content></ng-content></td>
    `
})
export class MyTableColComponent { 
}
```

Regards

Comment: Is the filter supposed to be a search field that filters automatically or with a 'search' button?

Comment: yes, automatically after keyup

Comment: why to waste time and effort when you have an **ng2-table** here http://valor-software.com/ng2-table/ Follow the documentation for setting up

Answer (score 5):

**update Angular 5**

`ngOutletContext` was renamed to `ngTemplateOutletContext`

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-beta5-2017-08-29

**original**

For your example creating a new component for row and col seems unnecessary.

With a simple filter pipe like

```ts
@Pipe({ name: 'filter' })
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(data: any[], filter:string) {
    console.log('filter', data, filter);
    if(!data || !filter) {
      return data;
    }
    return data.filter(row => row.some(col => col && col.indexOf(filter) >= 0));
  }
}
```

and a table component like

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'my-table',
    template: `
<div style="width: 100%">
  <div style="float: left; height: 50px; width: 100%">
    Search: 
    <input type="text" 
        [(ngModel)]="filterValue" 
        name="filter"
        style="height: 30px; border: 1px solid silver"/> 
      {{filterValue}}
  </div>
  <div style="float: left; width: 100%">
    <table>
      <tr *ngFor="let row of data | filter:filterValue">
        <td *ngFor="let col of row let index=index">
          <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="templates && templates[index]" [ngOutletContext]="{$implicit: col}"></template>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
    `
})
export class MyTableComponent { 
  filterValue: string;
  @ContentChildren(TemplateRef) templateRefs:QueryList<TemplateRef>;
  @Input() data:any[];
  templates:TemplateRef[];

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.templates = this.templateRefs.toArray();
  }
}
```

it can be used like

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
<my-table [data]="data">
  <template let-col>1: {{col}}</template>
  <template let-col>2: {{col}}</template>
  <template let-col>3: {{col}}</template>
</my-table>
  `,
})
export class App {
  data = [
    ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'],
    ['cat', 'dog', 'bird'],
    ['car', 'bicycle', 'airplane'],
  ];
}
```

where row and column data is passed to an input and the layout for the cells passed as `<template>` elements (one for each column - some additional checks are probably useful like checking if the number of templates is >= the number of columns in `data`).

Comment: It has to be used new component because it is my stylized table with sorting and search functionality

Comment: You can use custom components without any change in my approach. If you want to use the `<table>` element, you need to use attribute selectors for your custom components like `<tr my-table-row>`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556277/angular2-table-rows-as-component/34556489

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is quite easy to integrate [DataTabes](https://datatables.net/) directly without using third party wrapper. Typings are already available in npm. It gives you opportunity to gradually extend your wrapper with required features.