# Angular dynamic table creation

Tags: angular

I would like to create a dynamic table using angular, but I don't know where to start. I have done the tour of heroes tut and i want to move forward. 
The table would later become a calendar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a custom table component like this.
[Custom angular2 table](https://medium.com/@ct7/building-a-reusable-table-layout-for-your-angular-2-project-adf6bba3b498)

Comment: Then you can create a shared module with a table component and calender component and include the shared module in your module.

Comment: But when I tried I don't get a proper row or header or anything like that and I don't know why.

Comment: [I want something similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556277/angular2-table-rows-as-component).. but I don't understand how the code works

Comment: I don't have enough reputation.. :(