# In Angular2+, how can I replace a <tr> with my own component without interfering with the dom structure/css

Tags: angular

Consider the following table snippet with a rows of people and their result on a test:

```
<tr>
  <td>John Doe</td>
  <td>18</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Jane Dober</td>
  <td>28</td>
</tr>
<my-own-tr-component></my-own-tr-component>
```

In the end of the table above, I want to add a final `<tr>`, which will be my custom component, which will be reused elsewhere.

The problem is that my custom component inserts a dom element in a table which is not a `<tr>` which breaks the DOM, styling etc.

How can I make Angular NOT insert its own host element and just display the `<tr>` from my custom component?

I don't want to use attribute selectors since it seems like a hack, and is against Angulars style guide document.

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/a/34556489/1168786

Comment: Try `:host { display: table-row; }`.

Comment: @torazaburo you should post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the component the `table-row` display property:

```
:host { display: table-row; }
```

That will make it behave for all practical purposes like `<tr>`. To be precise, it is the `display: table-row` property defined in the user agent style sheet that makes `<tr>` function as a table row.