# Creating dynamic md-expansion-panel component inside md-accordion

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am dynamically creating component inside md-accordion component as below

```
<md-accordion [displayMode]="displayMode" [multi]="multi"
                class="md-expansion-demo-width">
    <ng-container #piechartsContainer>

    </ng-container>
</md-accordion>

@ViewChild("piechartsContainer", {read: ViewContainerRef}) pieChartContainer: ViewContainerRef;

let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(CreatePieChartElement);
let componentRef = this.pieChartContainer.createComponent(componentFactory);
```

here is the component I am inserting

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-pie-element',
  template: 
    <md-expansion-panel>
      <md-expansion-panel-header>{{title}}</md-expansion-panel-header>
    </md-expansion-panel>
  ,
  styles: [],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

It is obvious according to angular that it will look `<md-accordion><app-create-pie-element><md-expansion-panel>....` in html structure. How to achieve `<md-accordion><md-expansion-panel>` this structure,

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34556489/5202960) answer is helpful when creating components by loops. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution could be having `ng-template` that will wrap `CreatePieChartElement` template:

**CreatePieChartElement.html**

```html
<ng-template #tmpl>
  <md-expansion-panel>
    <md-expansion-panel-header>{{title}}</md-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </md-expansion-panel>
</ng-template>
```

**CreatePieChartElement.ts**

```typescript
@ViewChild('tmpl') template: TemplateRef<any>;
```

Then in parent component

```typescript
let componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(CreatePieChartElement);
let componentRef = componentFactory.create(this.pieChartContainer.injector);
...
this.pieChartContainer.createEmbeddedView(componentRef.instance.template);
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/6HfChaoEkN8xYNO58UkA?p=preview)**

Comment: This is working but I can't achieve one expansion panel expanded at once property ("multi" attribute in md- accordion). It works in normal scenario

Comment: I see. Check my updated plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/8a3BvrRCHrFXlzeau5LT?p=preview