# using directive for table row items without duplicating th

Tags: html, angular

**users-component.html**

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead class="text table-head-font">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>         
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr (dblclick)="selectUser()">
            <td>{{id}}</td>
            <td>{{firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{lastName}}</td>            
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**app.component.html**

> This will render thead for every record inside table, which I want to avoid.

*I tried to refactor this to put table tr items inside users-component.html and table header to leave outside in app.component like*
**app.component.html**

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead class="text table-head-font">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>         
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <users *ngFor="let user of users" (openUser)="getUser($event)" [id]="user.Id" [firstName]="this.firstName" [lastName]="this.lastName"></users>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**users-component.html**

```
<tr (dblclick)="selectUser()">
    <td>{{id}}</td>
    <td>{{firstName}}</td>
    <td>{{lastName}}</td>            
</tr>
```

*But this renders everything under first td, rest of td and tr are empty.*

**Update**

**users-component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'users',
    templateUrl: './users-component.html'
})
```

Comment: keep you `*ngFor` on `tr` in users-component.html and pass users array as input

Answer (score 0):

In `users-component.ts` add a `tr` selector:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'tr',
    ...
})
```

Then in `app.component.html` use the `users-component` like this:

`<tr users></tr>`

Comment: wont this create issue/conflict with html `tr` selector

Comment: I already using selector users inside component. I updated the question.

Comment: The DOM does not let you have a table row component. That is why you have to use `tr` as a selector. Check this posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556277/angular2-table-rows-as-component

Comment: If I already using users selector inside users-component how can I add tr selector on same component?

Comment: @user1765862 You can define multiple selectors for a single component

Answer (score 0):

Below is a way that can help you achieve this. You can pass you user list as an `Input` to the user component and then there itself display the users. Names may vary according to your choice.

Below is the code for reference.

Here is a live **[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jxuknk)** of the below code
**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  userList = [
    {
      id:"1",
      name:"user1",
      email:"shadfh@gfh.com"
    },
     {
      id:"2",
      name:"user2",
      email:"shadfh@gfh.com"
    },
     {
      id:"3",
      name:"user3",
      email:"shadfh@gfh.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<users [users]="userList"></users>
```

**user.component.html**

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead class="text table-head-font">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>         
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let user of users" (dblclick)="selectUser()">
            <td>{{user.id}}</td>
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.email}}</td>            
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**user.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'users',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: [  ]
})
export class UserComponent  {
  @Input() users: any;
}
```

Hope this  helps :)