# Ionic2 replace component selector with its content

Tags: typescript, angular, components, ionic2

I'm using Ionic2 and typescript.
Lets assume I want a custom component to have the content of a ion-menu.

```
<sidemenu></sidemenu> //this sidemenu will hold the ion.menu.

<ion-nav id="nav"
         [root]="rootPage"
         #content
         swipe-back-enabled="false">
</ion-nav>
```

The sidemenu template:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>{{ 'HELLO' | translate }}</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>

    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <button ion-item
                    *ngFor="let p of DataMenu"
                    (click)="openPage(p)">
                {{p.Title}}
            </button>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

But this will render the following html, breaking the menu navigation, css, etc... making the menu not to open.

```
<sidemenu>
   <ion-menu>
       ...
   </ion-menu>
</sidemenu>
<ion-nav>
    ...
</ion-nav>
```

When I wanted something like:

```
<ion-menu>
       ...
</ion-menu>
<ion-nav>
    ...
</ion-nav>
```

It's not possible to replace the component with the template content?
How can a create custom components around the ionic components?

Answer (score 1):

> How can a create custom components around the ionic components?

Please check my answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936198/ionic-2-global-navbar-for-the-app/37808988#comment63111053_37808988). There you can see how to create a `custom component` for the `navbar` and how to modify it (if needed) in some pages.

=====================================================

**EDIT:**

> It's not possible to replace the component with the template content?

Just like [Tierry Templier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1873365/thierry-templier) says in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588933/how-to-remove-replace-the-angular2-components-selector-tag-from-html#answer-34589337)

> To quote the Angular 1 to Angular 2 Upgrade Strategy doc:
>
> Directives that replace their host element (replace: true directives
>   in Angular 1) **are not supported in Angular 2**. In many cases these
>   directives can be upgraded over to regular component directives. In
>   fact, it depends on what you want to do and you need to be aware that
>   Angular2 supports several things:
>
> Attribute directives - see
>   https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html
>
> Structural directives - see
>   https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html

So in your case, and just like [Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217408/g%C3%BCnter-z%C3%B6chbauer) suggests as a workaround you can use a selector in your component like

```
[myComponent]
```

and then use it like

```
<div myComponent>Hello My component</div>
```

or `[my-component]` and then use it like `<div my-component>Hello My component</div>`