# Angular2 selector tag breaks css parent/child relationship

Tags: angular

I have a template that is heavily dependent on parent child relationships when it comes to CSS styling.

A tag(selector) wraps the component markup (html). Is there a way to hide that ? or is that a feature of angular2 and no workaround is possible?

I understand they seem to have replaced the "replace:true" option in the directives in angular1

Thanks!

Comment: could you post some code to help understand what the issue is?

Comment: Same question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/41249483/2593877

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34589018/2593877)

Give this a shot, if you don't want `<special-comp></special-comp>` elements and would like `<div special-comp></div>` instead.

BUT Angular 2 warns you not to do this in their [**STYLE GUIDE**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#05-03)

in your parents view

```
<div>
    <div special-comp></div>
</div>
```

and then in your child's component

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core'
@Component({
    selector: "[special-comp]",
    templateUrl: "./path/to/template.html"
})

export class MyChildComponent {
    ...
}
```

This will create a `div` with a property special-comp RATHER than creating a html element `<special-comp>`

So when you inspect in chrome you will see

```
<div special-comp></div>
```

RATHER than

```
<special-comp></special-comp>
```

Comment: That would be correct. I was about to answer my own question :)

Comment: Haha nice! Glad you figured it out!