# Use custom component selector on <template> tag to avoid invalid HTML by template-tag

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular2-template

I have a child component that generates the rows of a table. Since Angular2  [messes the output with the component-selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588933/how-to-remove-replace-the-angular2-components-selector-tag-from-html) which would result in invalid html like `<my-child-component>` in a table row, I need to get rich of this. The solution in the other question is not suiteable cause I need to access the `<tr>` element in the child component.

My idea is to use `<template>` tag with the attribute of my child component:

```
@Component({
    selector: '[childRow]',
    template:  `
<tr>
<td>Test</td>
</tr>
       `
    });
```

In master component

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <template childRow></template>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Result in exception

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: Components on an
>   embedded template: TimetableRowComponent

Its caused by the `<template>` tag.  Using another element like `<div childRow>` works fine, like also the component selector `<childRow>` (in this case of course without sqare brackets in the selector of the child component).

How can I solve this? My goal is as I said to generate valid html. So I don't want to have `<childRow>`, `<div>` or any other elements in the output, that are not valid inside an HTML table. This seems to work using `<template>` like this example:

```
<template ngFor let-row [ngForOf]="myArray">
      <tr>
          {{row.memberA}}</td>
      </tr>
</template>
```

But why can't I let Angular 2 render a child-template inside the `<template>` tag?

Comment: What about `<tr childRow>`?

Comment: I don't get how that is related to `<template>` and what the problem is with acessing it inside the child component.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer When I use `<tr childRow>`then Angular generates a `<tr>`element, so I couldn't generate my own `<tr>`in the child component. When I do this, I have two nested `<tr>`which is invalid and destroy the layout. I want a real template pseudo tag, that renders the anything whats inside my child-component, and nothing more. `<template>`should fit this since its rendered by Angular2.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I added a example of `<template>` which `ngFor`. This is just looping, without generating a element like when using `ngFor` on an HTML element like `<tr ngFor="..."``, the last one would create a `<tr>` element for each iteration. `<template>` would just loop without doing this. That's the behaviour I need, but not for loops, instead for rendering a child-component. I hope this make my problem/target better understandable.

Comment: No, `<template>` doesn't do this. `<template>` is just a container for Angular template content, that doesn't do anything on its own. It can just be used somewhere to create content. Perhaps a structural directive is what you are looking for. Structural directives can be applied to `<template>` and create content. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html

Comment: Exactly. `ngFor` is also a structural directive.