# Angular2 Component which renders 2 tr elements in a loop

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular

I need to write a component that has a template that looks like this:

```
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
```

This must be used with *ngFor to create a table.
The selector for the component is `spot-row`.
The component has one input variable named `spot`.

The desired output must look like this:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
</tbody>
<table>
```

I tried the following:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<spot-row *ngFor="let spot of spots" [spot]="spot"></spot-row>
</tbody>
<table>
```

But this produced

```
<table>
<tbody>
<spot-row>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
</spot-row>
</tbody>
<table>
```

Then I tried switching the component selector to `[spot-row]` and using `ng-container`

```
<table>
<tbody>
<ng-container spot-row *ngFor="let spot of spots" [spot]="spot"></ng-container>
</tbody>
<table>
```

But this produced an error

> Error: Error in ./SpotRowComponent class SpotRowComponent - inline
>   template:0:0 caused by: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node':
>   This node type does not support this method

Then I tried `template`

```
<table>
<tbody>
<template spot-row *ngFor="let spot of spots" [spot]="spot"></template>
</tbody>
<table>
```

But this also gives me an error

> Error: Template parse errors: Components on an embedded template:
>   SpotRowComponent ("     [ERROR ->]   
>   ")

I searched StackOverflow and found

- [Angular2 table rows as component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556277/angular2-table-rows-as-component)
  which is only about one tr
- [Angular2 : render a component without its wrapping tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38716105/angular2-render-a-component-without-its-wrapping-tag)
  where the question asks about tr elements and the accepted answer is
  about td elements
- [How to remove/replace the angular2 component's selector tag from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588933/how-to-remove-replace-the-angular2-components-selector-tag-from-html)
  which will render an additional div element

Comment: Maybe you can use `<tbody>` as a wrapping element? Should be valid HTML. (Remove outer `<tbody>`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggestion as per comment, not tested.

Component selector: `[spot-row]`

Component template:

```
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
```

HTML:

```
<table>
   <tbody *ngFor="let spot of spots" spot-row [spot]="spot"></tbody>
<table>
```

This should produce:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
     <tr>...</tr>
     <tr>...</tr>
   </tbody>
   <tbody>
     <tr>...</tr>
     <tr>...</tr>
   </tbody>
   ...
</table>
```

Which is valid (multiple `<tbody>` in `<table>`).

Comment: The tbody aproach is not perfect but it is working. The template aproach will generate an error, as mentioned in my question.

Comment: @wertzui Sorry, missed that part in your question.