# Angular 2: Component to render table with static <td>s and dynamic <td>s from another component

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I have an Angular 2 component which renders a nice table with kitten object data.

Since *some* of the columns are going to be reused in a different component, I'm looking for a way to extract the `<td>` into a separate component (`dynamic-kitten-tds`). I can not move `<td>`s which render `kitten.name` and `kitten.lastWashed` since they are unique to `cat-o-base` component:

### cat-o-base.component.html

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let kitten of kittenBasket">
        <td>{{ kitten.name }}</td>

        <dynamic-kitten-tds [value]="kitten"></dynamic-kitten-tds>

        <td>{{ kitten.lastWashed | date }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<table>
```

### dynamic-kitten-tds.component.html

The  entire template of the `dynamic-kitten-tds` component looks like this:

```
<td *ngFor="let preference of kitten.preferences">{{ preference | json }}</td>
```

#### Limitation 1

I may **not** use the `*ngFor` like this:

```
<td>{{ kitten.name }}</td>
<td *ngFor="let preference of kitten.preferences" [value]="preference"></td>
<td>{{ kitten.lastWashed | date }}</td>
```

This limitation comes from the business logic that must be implemented as a part of `dynamic-kitten-tds` component.

#### Limitation 2

The code must result in a valid DOM emission.

### Question

How do I achieve it? Using auxiliary components is fine. Using special structural directives is fine too.

#### P.S

I looked through some other SO questions (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696738/angular2-component-which-renders-2-tr-elements-in-a-loop)) however didn't find quite matching problem definition.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/EqMKNj29jNMI5DDowTR0?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using auxiliary components is fine here is my thought:

**dynamic-outlet.ts**

```
@Directive({selector: '[dynamicOutlet]'})
export class DynamicOutlet implements OnChanges, OnDestroy {
  @Input() dynamicOutlet: Type<any>;
  @Input() dynamicOutletModel: any;

  private componentRef: ComponentRef<any> = null;

  constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef) {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this.vcRef.clear();
    this.componentRef = null;

    if (this.dynamicOutlet) {
      const elInjector = this.vcRef.parentInjector;
      const componentFactoryResolver = elInjector.get(ComponentFactoryResolver);

      const componentFactory = componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.dynamicOutlet);
      this.componentRef = componentFactory.create(elInjector);

      this.componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
      this.componentRef.instance.model = this.dynamicOutletModel;
      this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.componentRef.instance.template, { $implicit: this.dynamicOutletModel });
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if(this.componentRef) {
      this.vcRef.clear();
      this.vcRef = null;
    }
  }
}
```

**kitten.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'kitten-component',
    template: `
      <ng-template let-model>
        <td *ngFor="let preference of model.preferences">{{ preference | json }}</td>
      </ng-template>
    `
})
export class Kitten {
  @ViewChild(TemplateRef) template: TemplateRef<any>;

  model: any;
}
```

and then you can use it like

**view**

```
<ng-container *dynamicOutlet="kittenComp; model: kitten"></ng-container>
```

**component**

```
kittenComp = Kitten;
```

Don't forget to add `Kitten` component to `entryComponents` array.

Here is **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/bPlD62ZKRl2Qs7emPiU8?p=preview)**

Comment: I actually solved it differently (will post my solution later), but your post works too, so I accept it. Thanks for your time and effort @yurzui !