# button group split in 2 components

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap has the following example of an action group.
The result is that the buttons inside the group are merged together.

Inside my Angular project I already have a toolbar and wanted to apply these styles on them. Basically I have a `ToolbarComponent` and an `ActionComponent`.

[image: concept]

The idea works fine as long as I put everything in 1 component without the sublevel of an `ActionComponent`. But when I seperate them (as shown in the picture above), then things don't work any more.

The buttons are not merged (look at the corners of the buttons).

[image: defect]

When I open the runtime html code in google chrome, it shows the following:

[image: source]

As you can see, **there's a level in-between the `<div class="btn-group">` and `<div class="btn">`.** (i.e. the tag of the `ActionComponent` itself: `<objt-action>`). My best guess, is that this tag messes things up.

**My best guess, is that this additional tag breaks the bootstrap logic.**

So, now I'm wondering about the best **strategy** to solve my problem.

## VIEW CODE OF `ToolbarComponent`

```
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-start" role="toolbar" aria-label="toolbar">

<!-- iterate action-groups -->
<div *ngFor="let actionGroup of actionGroups" class="btn-group p-1" role="group">

  <!-- for each action-group, iterate thru the actions of the group -->
  <ng-template ngFor let-action [ngForOf]="actionGroup.actions">
    <objt-action [action]="action" (actionClicked)="actionClicked($event)"></objt-action>
  </ng-template>

</div>

</div>
```

## EDIT

In mean time, I also tried it by changing the directive of the component, from `objt-action` to `[objt-action]`. By doing so, I can define the `ActionComponent` as follows inside the `ToolbarComponent`'s view:

```
  <div objt-action> </div>
```

But the resulting xml is still invalid, there still remains a disturbing intermediate level, i.e. the `<div objt-action>` itself.

Comment: I don't get what the problem is. What's the code that results in this DOM?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I added the code of the `ToolbarComponent`'s view. I left out the typescript code because it's quiet long and irrelevant I think. Thanks for having a look.

Answer (score 1):

With the approach mentioned in [How to remove/replace the angular2 component's selector tag from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588933/how-to-remove-replace-the-angular2-components-selector-tag-from-html/34589018?noredirect=1#comment78846291_34589018) you need to make this element `<div class="action-group" aria-label="Basic example">` the component.

What you tried is to have a component that doesn't add a tag at all, that is not possible. 
You could use a structural directive and use it like

```
<div class="action-group" aria-label="Basic example">
  <ng-container *myDirective></ng-container>
</div>
```

and then let `*myDirective` generate the buttons.

See also https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives

Comment: looks promising, I'll give it a go. :)

Comment: I did find examples of directives creating attributes, and 1 example of a structural directive creating an embedded view `this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);` to show/hide its body. But I didn't find any example of a directive that actually creates html tags. (e.g. buttons) - I checked the source of "Bootstrap powered Angular" for their code for tabs. Because it's a similar problem: Found a `TabSet` component with Tab directives. But still the `TabSet` component that contains the html. So, I'm starting to have doubts if this is possible. - An example would be appreciated.

Comment: If you use `<button *myDirective></button>`, then `templateRef` will refer to `<button></button>`, so your code will actually add `<button></button>`

Comment: You can add the same template multiple times.

Comment: I guess that summarizes your answer to: "move most html to the root component". ... which is a reasonable solution.

Comment: I mentioned several approaches. One of them might turn out this way, yes :D