# How to Separate List Items into Components in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Suppose I am creating a typical to-do list that has a structure as following:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1 - description for item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2 - description for item 2</li>
    <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

I would like the list and the items to be as reusable as possible, and so I can make them into separate components:

#### todo-list.component.*

```
@Component({
    selector: "todo-list",
    templateUrl: "todo-list.component.html"
})
export class TodoListComponent { /* ... */ }
```

```
<ul>
    <li todo-list-item *ngFor="let item of items" [item]="item"></li>
</ul>
```

#### todo-list-item.component.*

```
@Component({
    selector: "li[todo-list-item]",
    templateUrl: "todo-list-item.component.html"
})
export class TodoListItemComponent { /* ... */ }
```

```
{{ item.title }} - {{ item.description }}
```

---

So far everything will work as long as I stick with native HTML elements such as `ul` and `li`.

However an issue arises when I try to use Angular components instead native elements such as `mat-list` and `mat-list-item`:

#### todo-list.component.*

```
<mat-list>
    <mat-list-item todo-list-item *ngFor="let item of items" [item]="item"></mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

#### todo-list-item.component.*

```
{{ item.title }} - {{ item.description }}
```

---

The snippets above **do not** work. `mat-list-item` does not accept `item` and also now there are two component definitions that matches `mat-list-item[todo-list-item]`.

I can do it this way:

#### todo-list.component.*

```
<mat-list>
    <todo-list-item *ngFor="let item of items" [item]="item"></todo-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

#### todo-list-item.component.*

```
<mat-list-item>
    {{ item.title }} - {{ item.description }}
</mat-list-item>
```

---

However now the structure is not correct and it **will not** produce the correct styling:

```
<mat-list>
    <todo-list-item>
        <mat-list-item>Item 1 - description for item 1</mat-list-item>
    </todo-list-item>
    <todo-list-item>
        <mat-list-item>Item 2 - description for item 2</mat-list-item>
    </todo-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

`mat-list-item` should be directly under `mat-list`:

```
<mat-list>
    <mat-list-item>Item 1 - description for item 1</mat-list-item>
    <mat-list-item>Item 2 - description for item 2</mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

---

I am aware that I can combine the two components into a single one, however each of the list items can be fairly complex (with buttons and additional logic) that I would like them to be in separate components. What is the usual approach to this problem? Many of the related questions (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480243) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556277)) that I could find assume native elements are used, which is not the case here. Specifically, how do I create the following structure using two components that I can define myself?

```
<todo-list>
    <mat-list>
        <mat-list-item>Item 1 - description for item 1</mat-list-item>
        <mat-list-item>Item 2 - description for item 2</mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>
</todo-list>
```

Comment: When you say `mat-list-item` does not accept `item` what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @fuzz [`mat-list-item`](https://material.angular.io/components/list/api#MatListItem) is an Angular component that is already defined instead of a native HTML element that I can redefine by using the selector. Because of that, I don't have control over its inputs.

Comment: how exactly is the Styling off

Comment: @NikolaiKiefer Let's just say the structure needs to be exact where `mat-list-item` has to be directly under `mat-list`. The styling being incorrect is just a side-effect caused by the incorrect structure.

Comment: could you provide a screenshot of the styling

Answer (score 3):

todo-list.component.*

```
<mat-list>
    <todo-list-item *ngFor="let item of items" [item]="item"></todo-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

todo-list-item.component.*

```
<mat-list-item>
    {{ item.title }} - {{ item.description }}
</mat-list-item>
```

You're example is looking promising

however have you tried

```
<mat-list>
   <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of items" >
     <todo-list-item [item]></todo-list-item>
   </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

todo-list-item.component.*

```
    <p>{{ item.title }} - {{ item.description }}</p>
```

that way it should be quaranted a mat list item under mat list

Comment: are you sure because the ngfor is different in your example

Comment: Sorry about that. Upon reading it again I have noticed that you have moved `*ngFor` up and onto `mat-list`. This will create a separate `mat-list` for each `item`s which is not correct as well.

Comment: i tried some options,let me know if the edit is working for you. Or do you get problems with the logic then