# How to make angular2 not wrap items?

Tags: javascript, angular

All arranged, everything was fine until it became necessary to create a component which is TR.And when inserting that component onto the page Angular2 does the following:

```
<my-component>
  <tr>...</tr>
</my-component>
```

It all falls down and bleeds. How can I make it not do that? Where to look? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 + Semantic UI , component encapsulation breaks style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34707029/angular-2-semantic-ui-component-encapsulation-breaks-style)

Answer (score 1):

In fact there is no more support for the "replace: true" feature of Angular1.

You could leverage an attribute in the selector to attach the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: '[my-component]'
  (...)
})
```

and use it this way:

```
<div my-component>
  <tr>...</tr>
</div>
```