# Angular 2 invisible component container

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Containers like `<app-root></app-root>` can do break the css layout, especially if working with flexbox.

Is it possible to have invisible component containers? I tried `selector: '[app-root]'` already with the following tags, but they all create a dom element:

```
<template>, <ng-template>, <ng-template>, <ng-container>
```

If this container is really needed, would be awesome if Angular would just render an HTML comment.

Comment: "Is it possible to have invisible component containers" does this mean that you don't wanna show the tag in the DOM? @Mick

Comment: Yes just the content of the component without any container

Comment: what do you mean by **just the content**?? you dont want the selector tag? in your HTML DOM??

Comment: I don't get your purpose of doing so. If you want to hide some templates according to a condition add an *ngIf="" directive.

Try to make the question much clear

Comment: Just no <app-container-tag></app-container-tag> whats so hard to understand there. The component template without any container html dom tag.

Comment: I thought so, too. It works e.g. for *ngIf an becomes a html-tag: `<!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}-->` But in this case it stays a html-tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove the host HTML element selectors created by angular component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34280475/remove-the-host-html-element-selectors-created-by-angular-component)

Comment: `<ng-container>` doesn't create a DOM element, but it also doesn't do what you want.

Comment: It does when using like so: `<ng-container app-root></ng-container>

Answer (score 4):

Personally I think the best way is to use `selector` as an attribute. For example, you have @Component like this:

```
...
@Component({
    selector: '[your-component]'
})
...
```

This way, `your-component` is an attribute, which you can use like this:

```
<div your-component>Some content...</div>
```

In this case you **guarantee** that styles won't break.

**P.S.** as far as I know this feature (`replace` in Angular 1) was deprecated in Angular 1, so it is not something that you would expect from  Angular 2.

Comment: But i don't want no container at all, not even <div>

Comment: @Mick, you can't. ``Replace`` functionality was deprecated in Angular 1

Comment: @AngularFrance, simple, with ``ng-content``

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed for creating a component in an HTML table. I was able to put my template directly on the tbody element and all of the rendering errors were fixed!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `display: contents` on the host element to make it invisible to flexbox and grid layouts. The element does appear in the DOM, but it won't interfere with layout: its children will obey the layout rules of their grand-parent.

Unfortunately, `display: contents` is only available in Firefox right now, but support will grow with time. https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents