# Html table in conflict with angular component header and component body

Tags: angular, html-table

Im trying to make from scratch a table in angular. I want that my header and body be dynamic.

```
<my-datatable>
  <my-header header></my-header>
  <my-body body></my-body>
</my-datatable>
```

and my header component is

```
<thead >
  <tr>
      <th style="text-align: left;"   *ngFor="let field of fields | async ">
        {{ field  }}
      </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

my body component is

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of items | async ; let rowIndex = index; " > 
      <td *ngFor="let field of fields | async; let colIndex = index;" >
        {{ item[field] }}
      </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

my datatble component

```
<table>
      <ng-content select="[header]"></ng-content>
      <ng-content select="[body]"></ng-content>
</table>
```

The table is displayed but is showed like two tables, even when I inspect just show one table.

[this is a plnkr with the example](https://plnkr.co/edit/uwMm71UtH1FLFqVKfJR8?p=preview)

Comment: seems you're not using `<table>` to wrap your `thead` and `tbody` templates.

Comment: @lexith Im in  my-datatable component

Comment: How does that component look like?

Comment: @lexith update my answer, is the basic table component with header and body as "dynamic components"

Answer (score 8):

I think I'm a little late to the party, but for anyone else who found this post via Google, here is a cleaner solution that does not involve changing the CSS.

Try an **attribute selector** in place of an **element selector**. In short, change:

```
selector: "my-head"
```

to

```
selector: "[myHead]"
```

and modify the template to not include thead or tbody.

Then when you'd like to use the component, instead of

```
<my-head></my-head>
```

use

```
<thead myHead>...</thead>
```

Here is a link to a modified version of the original plunker with the modified change https://plnkr.co/edit/tIXePumNbA3iqTmCd8vK?p=preview

This post may also be of interest [Remove the host HTML element selectors created by angular component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34280475/remove-the-host-html-element-selectors-created-by-angular-component)

Answer (score 0):

You will fix you problem setting the tag table with style="display:grid"

```
<table style="display:grid">
```

In any case you will need to sync your headers with your body "manually"

[This is the solution](https://plnkr.co/edit/nvORcBvFKo73IrRGrL6y), if you delete the the grid you will have your problem

Comment: its look like i need to do it. but should not the tag be like an empty tag?

Comment: @Methescripter yep, it should. If you delete the components tag the css fix it self. I believe that the behavior is not the correct one.