# Hover over a building floor in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm trying to change the color of a floor when I hover it.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E26AS.jpg this is the image on which I'm trying to do it.

I tried the answer on this post: [How can we draw 3D bulding structure from existing image Jquery,Css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28493530/how-can-we-draw-3d-bulding-structure-from-existing-image-jquery-css) but when I actually hover the floor it doesn't work, it only shows when I hover in a random place on the bottom of the image.

How can I do it so it shows that specific floor when I hover it, and how can I actually implement the map attribute for every floor?

Here's my code if it helps:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('map').on('mouseenter', function () {
            $('.highlight-4').show();
        })

        $('map').on('mouseleave', function () {
            $('.highlight-4').hide();
        })
    });
```

```css
.highlight {
     z-index: 9999;
     display: none;
     pointer-events: none;
  }

  .building {
     position: absolute;
     margin-left: 11%;
     box-shadow: 0 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML

        <img class="highlight highlight-4" src="/static/floor-4.png" alt="">
        <img class="highlight highlight-3" src="/static/floor-3.png" alt="">
        <img class="highlight highlight-2" src="/static/floor-2.png" alt="">
        <img class="highlight highlight-1" src="/static/floor-1.png" alt="">
        <img class="highlight highlight-0" src="/static/floor-0.png" alt="">
        <img usemap="#image-map" class="building" src="/static/apartments.jpeg" alt="">
        <map name="image-map">
            <area target="" alt="" title="" href="" coords="1121,326,197,662,191,747,1130,473,1398,664,1387,544"
                shape="poly">
        </map>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way seems to implement your building image as an SVG file with **`<polyline>`** overlays. This way you can use CSS selectors and have much more control over your layouts. You can use `<a>` inside SVG, javascript, etc.

I took your image and loaded it in [Draw SVG](https://www.drawsvg.org/drawsvg.html) to create the required *top floor* `<polyline>`. After having saved the DrawSVG drawing locally I simply copied the `<polyline>` into my own SVG file, which, as you can see, works without any further HTML and added some CSS to do the highlighting on `:hover`.

You can insert this SVG into you html as if it were an `<img>`, it is just another tag (with benefits).

**UPDATE**

Revisited the original code I posted and replaced it with completely new code. The code is now a HTML page using an SVG file with the OPs image and showing how to use an `<a>` with some demo text on `:hover` (top floor again).

The HTML page has also been made 'responsive' by using math in CSS `calc()` and `@media` queries (go 'full-page' and resize browser, also check the page on various devices with the browser *Developer Tools*, 'portrait' and 'landscape' mode).

Explanation of the math can be found in other answers I gave on SO:

- [SO 62033317](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62033317/2015909)
- [SO 61867702](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61867702/2015909)

Now you create the other floors....

```css
/*
    Visit below answers on Stackoverflow for an explanation
    of the math used for responsive sizing of elements.

    https://stackoverflow.com/a/62033317/2015909
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/61867702/2015909
*/
/**************************/
/* preferred global rules */
/**************************/
html,body               { box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; max-width: 100%; height: 100% }
*::before,*::after, *   { box-sizing: inherit }
body                    { margin: 0 }

/* responsive base font size using y = mx + b */
html    { font-size: calc(0.625vmin + 0.75rem) } /* (320,14)(1280,20) */
body    { font-size: 1rem }

[band]  { display: flex; flex-flow: column wrap; align-content: center }

[padded="1"], [padded="0"] [band*="padded"] {
/*
    responsive page padding
    and responsive band padding (same as responsive page padding, but at band level)
    p1(320,32) p2(1920, 72) => 0.025x + 24
    p3(320, 8) p4(1920,320) => 0.195x - 54.4 

    'Band padding' is only active when 'page padding' is off 
*/
    padding: calc( 2.5vh + 24px) calc(19.5vw - 54.4px);
}

/* Making sure the image fits in any viewport, either portrait or landscape */
@media (orientation: portrait ) { #construction-site { height: auto; width: 100% } }
@media (orientation: landscape) { #construction-site { height: 100%; width: auto } }
```

```html
<body padded="0">
<div id="construction-site" band="padded">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 1600 1200"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

        <style>
            .line       { stroke: Black; stroke-opacity: 0; stroke-width: 2px; cursor: pointer } 
            .polyline   { fill  : Red  ; fill-opacity  : 0 }
    
            .floor-text { fill: Black; stroke: none; fill-opacity: 0;
                          cursor: default; pointer-events: none;
                          font-weight: bold; font-family: sans-serif;
                          /* responsive font using y = mx + b */
                          font-size: calc(-1vmin + 51.2px); /* (320,48)(1920,32) */
                        }

            .floor:hover>.line       { fill-opacity: .4; stroke-opacity: .8 }
            .floor:hover>.floor-text { fill-opacity: .7 }
        </style>

        <image href="https://i.imgur.com/0i4N0d3.jpg"/>

        <a id="top-floor" class="floor" rel="noopener" target="_blank" href="javascript:void(0)" title="top floor, click for details...">
            <polyline class="line polyline" 
                points="201.242,678.473 1121.43, 333.16 1370.24,
                        553.473 1387.74, 668.473 1127.49,
                        474.098 189.242, 753.473 202.242, 678.973"/>

            <line class="line" x1="1121.42" y1="333.472" x2="1127.45" y2="474.097"/>
            <text class="floor-text" x="800" y="150" text-anchor="middle">top floor demo text</text>
        </a>
    </svg>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'll try to implement the other floors, but you're right, it works. Thank you :)

Comment: I do actually have a question, i didnt work with drawing svg before, what shape do I use to draw the exact floor? The rectangle shape doesn't seems to work well

Comment: So to answer my own question I figured it out, if you want to do it yourself just select from elements polyline, and then draw your shape, and then you can open the image in another tab and inspect it, copy the polyline and you're all set. Thank you very much for the answer Rene :)

Comment: For irregular shapes you can use either `<polyline>` or `<path>`. [MDN: Basic shapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Basic_Shapes). But I advice you to do some basic stuff in an app like **DrawSVG** or **InkScape**, save the SVG file and open it in an editor to see how things work. Bit of a learning curve...

Comment: Yeah, it resembles `<img>` and `<map><area>`, but not quite and with much more possiblities. Well worth the study!! Furthermore, an SVG can be a standalone document (like a HTML), or posted inline (like I did) and can also be used as a `background-image`. Lots of possibilities.

Comment: Totally unrelated, but here are 2 demos I made on Codepen a while back: [Toggle SVG design grid with SVG on top](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/WNvXMMX) and [Toggle SVG design grid as body background](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/VwLrQao). Just to give you an idea.....

Comment: I never knew you can do so much with SVG's, damn this is a good day :))