# How to write <p> on hover at specific part of SVG image

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I drawed a map and converted it to SVG. I need to write the name of the neighborhoods as soon as the user hovers the mouse on it.

I don't know how to do it, and either how to select the specific area of a neighborhood in order to do the changes.

Here's the print of that part of the website:

https://i.postimg.cc/vZcbrjYR/home-1.jpg

.

So people were questioning for more info for a complete answer. Here`s the code I used on HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 content-area">
    <object style="width: 500px; margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom: 30px;" type="image/svg+xml" data="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/mapa-goiania-traco.svg"></object>
</div>
```

And here's the SVG code: https://ufile.io/y15c73mb

Just to mention, my biggest struggle now is how to separate on SVG the specific area of the states in order to do the CSS changes. Cause when I open the SVG file, it all appears just a big mass of numbers that doesn't make difference of the area of one state or another. I wish to select them exactly to work with CSS on it.

Comment: can you please post more code and/or the svg code? I can't really help you with just a JPG file.

Comment: Ideally I would need the HTML code or the relevant parts of it, plus the SVG or its full code or even better the full live preview.

Comment: But looking at your map, I know how to do it, I have done something similar in the past.

Comment: Hi Renato, welcome at SO! FYI, you are supposed to post a [reprex]. In the mean time, you can give SVG elements a classname and/or ID (e.g. `<path class="south-america" id="brasil">`) and use CSS `:hover` to display some SVG text ( `<text class="capital">Rio de Janeiro</text>` with CSS `.capital { visibility="hidden" } .south-america:hover .capital { visibility="visible" }` ). Or something like that (will need some work).

Comment: Hey guys! Thanks for the tips. Could you take a look at my new editions? I'm stuck in the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal demo so you can play around, but as Rene suggested applying the classes (i.e. in my example, paris, etc.) would be more accurate if on the SVG elements, but it all depends on your SVG code. If it's not possible, I would recommend using a relative positioning for the SVG itself, and then position each section absolutely so it gives you a fine control over things.

```css
.container {
    display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;
}

.map {
  background:lightgray;
  width:500px;height:500px;margin-top:250px;
}

.square {
  width:250px;height:250px;cursor:pointer;
}

.paris {
  background:blue;
}

.paris span {
  width:50%;margin-left:25%;
margin-top:25%;visibility:hidden;color:#FFF;}

.paris:hover span {
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="map">
    <div class="square paris">
      <span>Paris (France)</span>
    </div>
    <div class="square montreal"></div>
    <div class="square boston"></div>
    <div class="square istanbul"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my comment I copied [File:Brazil State RiodeJaneiro.svg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Brazil_State_RiodeJaneiro.svg) from WikiMedia (all rights by the original owner!) and simplified it somewhat (removed most paths) for the below snippet.

I inserted `<text class="capital">` below the `<path class="capital">` of the *State of Rio de Janeiro* and hide that text by default. When `:hover` the *State of Rio de Janeiro* (in dark red), I show the text using the *adjacent selector (+)* [w3schools: CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

All CSS code is inside the SVG file, so it will not only work when the SVG is used in your HTML, but also when you open the SVG-file in your browser.

The running SVG is on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/XWdZxwo?editors=1000) (as the file is too large for SO), but below is the relevant code as I commented earlier.

In another answer on *Stackoverflow* I did something similar showing text (responsively) when hovering the top floor of an image of a building: [SO62099505](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62101723/2015909)

**CSS inside SVG**

```
<style>
    .capital {
        visibility: hidden;   /* hide text by default */
        pointer-events: none; /* ignore cursor over text, prevents hover 'jitter' */

        /* Just demo eye-candy */
        font-weight   : bold;
        font-size     : 2800px;
        letter-spacing: 100px;

        fill: White;
        fill-opacity: 1;
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 75;
    }
    .estado { fill: FireBrick; cursor: pointer } /* show pointer hand cursor */
    .estado:hover+.capital { visibility: visible } /* show text element adjacent to (below) path element */
</style>
```

**SVG Code**

```
    <g id="Estados">
        <!-- State of Rio de Janeiro -->
        <path class="estado" d="M143583 140702l32 -32 0 -32 0 -32 65 -32 32 0 0 -32 32 0 32 -33 64 0 33 -32 -33 -64 65 -32 -32 -32 64 -33 -32 -32 32 -32 -32 0 32 -64 -32 0 0 -32 -32 0 32 -32 0 -33 0 -32 0 -32 32 -32 0 -32 32 -32 0 -65 32 -32 0 -32 -32 0 32 -64 -32 -32 32 -33 0 -32 0 -32 32 0 32 0 65 0 32 0 32 0 0 -32 32 -32 -32 -32 64 -65 97 -64 32 -32 32 32 32 0 33 0 32 0 64 -96 64 64 97 -64 0 -33 32 -32 128 -64 33 0 96 -64 97 64 64 -32 64 -65 65 -32 64 -64 32 0 64 0 32 32 -32 64 32 0 0 33 33 0 0 32 96 -32 32 0 32 -33 32 -64 33 -32 32 0 64 0 0 32 32 0 32 0 65 0 225 -96 32 32 -32 32 32 0 0 -32 96 -64 65 0 0 32 64 -32 64 -129 65 0 0 -32 0 -32 -65 0 32 -33 -32 -32 0 -32 32 -64 65 0 -32 -32 96 -97 97 0 32 -32 -32 0 0 -32 32 0 64 -32 32 -32 0 -65 32 0 33 -32 0 -32 0 -32 -65 -64 -64 -65 32 -32 -32 -32 -32 0 -32 -32 0 -64 -33 0 -32 32 -32 -65 -32 0 -64 0 -33 33 -96 -65 -64 32 0 33 -32 -65 -33 0 -32 0 -32 -32 -32 32 -32 -64 -64 32 -33 -32 0 32 0 32 -32 -32 0 32 32 65 -32 0 -32 0 0 -97 -32 0 32 -64 -32 0 -32 0 -65 -32 -32 0 0 32 -64 32 0 32 32 32 0 32 -32 0 -32 -32 -65 0 -64 32 -32 33 -32 0 -32 32 -65 -32 -32 -33 -32 0 32 33 -96 128 -32 0 -32 -32 -65 0 -32 0 32 32 -32 0 0 -32 64 -64 -32 0 -32 0 -64 -65 -65 33 -32 -65 -64 129 -32 0 -32 -64 -33 -33 0 33 -32 32 -64 -65 -32 33 -32 -33 -32 0 0 -96 0 -32 32 -97 -32 -32 -33 32 -32 -32 -96 32 0 -64 32 -32 -32 -64 -32 -33 -32 0 -33 -32 -64 0 0 -64 0 -32 -32 0 -32 -32 32 -65 0 -32 -32 -128 -65 -65 -64 -64 -64 0 -65 -32 -128 0 32 -65 32 -32 32 0 32 -32 33 0 64 -32 64 0 65 -64 32 0 96 64 65 -32 64 32 64 0 32 32 0 -32 65 -64 0 -32 96 -33 0 -64 32 -32 97 -32 32 0 32 32 64 -32 32 32 97 -32 0 32 64 0 0 -32 65 -32 0 -33 96 -32 129 -128 32 32 0 -32 0 -32 32 -65 32 0 32 0 32 -32 65 32 32 0 96 0 0 65 32 0 33 0 32 -33 64 -64 32 32 65 0 64 0 32 32 32 -32 64 0 33 -64 0 32 32 -32 32 0 32 0 32 32 0 -32 32 129 32 -33 33 33 32 -33 64 -32 0 -32 64 -32 0 32 33 0 64 -32 32 -64 32 0 32 0 33 0 32 -33 32 -64 32 32 32 -32 32 0 32 0 0 -64 0 -32 0 -32 33 32 64 -32 0 -33 0 -32 64 32 0 33 32 -33 32 0 0 -64 33 0 128 -32 0 -32 97 0 64 64 32 -32 32 0 32 -32 33 0 0 -32 96 -32 32 0 65 -33 192 -64 33 -32 64 0 0 -64 32 32 0 -32 32 0 32 -33 65 33 64 -33 64 -32 32 0 33 0 128 -96 32 0 33 0 0 32 32 32 -32 0 64 32 0 32 32 0 32 33 64 -97 65 0 32 0 32 -32 64 0 33 64 0 32 32 -32 0 -64 64 0 0 -32 32 0 32 0 65 64 32 -32 0 64 32 0 0 -32 0 -32 32 0 32 -64 32 0 33 -33 0 97 64 32 32 32 32 -32 161 -32 32 -64 32 0 32 32 0 32 65 0 64 0 64 0 129 -64 32 -33 64 0 129 -96 96 -64 0 -32 65 -33 32 0 32 33 64 0 32 -33 33 33 64 32 96 -32 65 0 32 -33 32 33 32 -33 32 33 0 32 32 32 33 0 32 32 32 0 32 -32 0 32 32 32 129 -96 32 0 0 32 64 32 32 0 65 0 0 64 0 65 -97 64 0 32 32 97 33 64 64 -32 0 -65 96 -32 65 0 64 0 0 32 129 -32 64 -96 32 -32 -32 -33 0 -32 64 -32 97 -32 32 0 128 -96 33 0 64 -33 193 -64 128 -128 0 -33 161 -64 257 -64 129 -65 32 -32 193 -96 193 -65 32 -32 97 -32 128 -32 65 -32 32 0 32 0 64 -32 0 -65 225 -96 322 -129 32 -32 322 -96 32 -65 32 0 96 -32 97 0 128 -32 0 -32 193 -64 0 -33 0 -32 0 -32 0 -64 -32 -32 -32 32 -32 -64 32 0 -32 -33 -65 -32 -32 0 -32 0 -32 0 -32 32 -32 0 -32 -32 0 -64 -65 0 -32 0 -32 -32 64 -64 -32 0 -32 -33 96 -128 33 -32 96 -65 -32 -32 0 -32 96 -32 0 -32 32 -33 0 -32 33 -32 64 0 32 -96 64 -32 33 -33 -65 -96 0 -32 -96 -32 32 -65 0 -32 0 -32 32 -32 0 -97 32 -32 32 32 65 0 32 -32 32 -32 -64 -32 -32 0 64 -32 0 -32 64 -32 -32 -65 32 -32 -32 -32 64 -32 -32 -32 -32 0 0 -33 32 -64 0 -128 32 -33 33 -32 64 -32 32 -32 32 -32 -32 -32 32 -65 -32 -32 0 32 -32 -32 0 -64 32 -32 -64 -129 32 0 0 -32 32 -32 0 -32 32 -33 32 -32 32 -64 33 0 0 -64 0 -65 128 0 0 -32 32 -32 0 -64 65 0 0 -32 96 -97 0 -32 0 -32 0 -32 32 32 65 0 0 -32 -33 -32 -64 -65 -32 0 -32 0 -32 -32 -33 0 -64 -64 0 -32 -64 -33 0 -32 64 -64 64 -32 33 32 32 0 0 -32 32 -32 64 -65 32 33 97 0 96 -33 32 -32 65 0 96 32 32 -32 97 32 0 -64 32 -32 0 32 32 -64 -32 -32 32 -33 0 -64 64 -32 -32 -32 32 -32 65 -32 32 -33 32 -32 -64 -64 64 -129 -32 -32 64 0 32 0 33 0 32 -32 64 0 32 -32 -32 -32 32 -32 32 0 65 -33 32 65 64 32 32 32 0 32 65 32 32 -32 -32 65 64 0 32 -33 96 0 33 0 0 33 64 0 0 64 32 -32 32 32 0 32 0 32 -32 97 32 64 0 32 65 -32 64 32 -32 0 -32 96 0 33 32 0 -32 96 -33 32 -32 0 32 97 65 32 0 128 32 0 0 65 -32 0 0 64 -32 32 64 32 -32 33 -32 0 0 32 32 64 0 64 -32 0 0 -32 -33 0 0 64 33 0 0 33 32 0 -65 128 0 32 33 0 32 0 64 0 0 33 -64 32 0 32 64 0 0 -32 64 0 32 32 33 0 0 32 32 -32 32 0 0 32 64 32 0 32 32 0 33 0 32 0 96 65 97 -33 32 65 64 32 0 32 32 32 32 -64 33 64 96 -32 64 64 0 -64 32 0 33 32 64 0 32 0 0 65 64 32 65 32 32 32 64 0 64 -64 33 0 0 -32 32 32 32 -32 32 32 32 0 32 0 0 -32 32 32 33 0 128 32 32 0 33 32 32 0 0 32 32 -32 64 96 32 0 32 0 33 33 0 -33 32 0 32 0 32 -64 64 0 33 0 32 0 0 32 32 0 0 32 64 0 32 33 32 0 33 0 0 32 0 -32 32 0 0 -33 0 33 32 -33 -32 33 32 0 64 0 32 0 65 -33 32 -32 64 0 97 -32 32 -32 32 32 32 0 32 32 32 0 65 32 64 97 64 -32 65 0 32 0 32 96 0 65 32 32 32 0 32 -32 0 32 33 0 0 32 32 0 0 32 32 0 0 64 -32 129 32 96 -32 0 -65 161 -32 0 -64 32 -32 97 -97 128 -64 65 -32 32 -97 96 -32 129 0 161 97 193 32 64 64 32 64 0 33 32 0 -32 0 32 -65 354 0 193 97 354 128 578 33 161 0 129 -65 128 -32 65 -64 32 -193 96 -161 97 -225 160 -129 97 -225 96 -193 65 -225 96 -643 161 -257 64 -257 97 -193 96 -129 32 -96 65 -322 160 -225 193 -64 0 -64 65 -33 32 0 64 33 0 -33 32 33 32 -97 65 -32 0 -129 64 -96 96 -64 65 0 64 -33 96 -32 0 -32 33 -64 0 -64 32 -65 128 -32 33 -32 64 -32 0 -32 -64 -65 32 -64 64 -32 64 -64 193 -33 65 0 192 0 33 0 32 65 257 32 64 96 0 0 32 65 97 64 64 64 0 32 -32 -32 -32 65 0 0 -32 64 32 32 -32 0 -65 32 33 0 -33 32 33 -32 32 64 32 -32 32 -32 0 -32 64 0 -32 -32 0 32 64 -32 -32 -32 32 -32 0 -33 -32 -64 32 -32 65 0 32 0 32 0 32 -64 -32 0 32 -129 32 -64 129 0 64 0 32 32 -32 -32 32 0 33 -32 32 -33 0 -32 32 0 -32 -32 0 -64 64 -32 32 -33 97 0 64 33 64 32 0 0 32 32 33 32 -33 32 -32 0 32 -32 33 32 0 32 0 -32 32 -32 -32 -32 32 32 0 -32 32 0 32 32 0 0 32 0 65 -32 -65 -97 -32 33 -32 -65 -32 -160 -65 -997 -64 -354 -32 -289 0 -258 0 -64 32 -96 -32 -354 0 -225 0 -193 32 -32 32 0 65 -32 0 -32 0 -97 -33 -450 33 -289 32 -225 32 -161 -32 -193 0 -64 32 -33 0 -32 0 -32 32 -32 -32 -32 0 -32 32 0 -32 32 0 -65 -64 -128 -33 -129 0 -32 -32 0 -32 -96 0 64 -32 0 -64 32 32 32 0 -32 32 32 0 32 0 33 -32 0 -64 -65 0 -32 -33 -32 0 -32 33 -32 -65 64 -32 0 -32 -64 -32 32 -32 32 0 32 32 32 -65 32 -64 65 -64 -32 -32 0 -32 64 -65 96 -64 -64 -32 -32 -32 64 -65 0 -32 32 -32 161 -96 0 -65 0 -32 -32 -32 0 -32 32 -32 -32 -32 32 -33 -32 0 -32 0 0 -32 -32 32 -33 -32 -32 0 -96 -32 -32 32 -65 0 -32 0 32 65 -32 -33 -32 33 0 32 -32 32 -32 32 -65 -32 -32 -32 -64 32 0 32 -64 0 -161 32 0 32 -32 32 -32 0 -33 0 -32 33 -32 0 32 32 -64 32 -32 0 32 0 -96 64 0 32 -33 32 33 0 -65 97 0 32 32 32 33 -32 0 32 32 32 64 65 32 32 32 96 32 -32 -32 -96 -32 -32 0 -33 -64 0 -32 -64 32 -32 32 32 32 0 0 -32 64 -64 33 -33 32 0 64 65 64 0 33 0 -33 -32 33 -33 32 0 32 -32 0 32 32 -32 32 0 0 32 -32 33 -64 64 0 32 32 64 32 0 -32 33 -32 -33 -32 65 -33 -65 -64 0 -32 -32 -64 32 -65 65 32 32 33 -32 0 32 32 32 -32 -32 -33 0 0 32 33 32 96 0 -64 32 32 32 -32 0 -65 0 33 33 32 0 64 -33 32 33 -64 64 32 32 64 -32 65 0 0 32 0 -32 0 32 32 0 32 0 -32 0 -32 0 32 32 64 0 0 65 -64 0 0 32 0 -32 32 32 -32 64 32 32 -32 0 -32 0 0 32 32 32 32 -64 64 0 -32 0 32 32 -64 32 32 0 0 33 -32 0 -96 64 0 32 32 32 -32 0 -33 0 -128 0 -129 65 -128 0 -65 32 0 32 -32 0 -32 -32 -32 -32 -65 -33 0 -32 -64 0 -32 -32 -96 -32 -65 0 -32 0 -64 32 -32 -32 -33 32 33 32 -33 -32 -32 32 32 0 0 32 97 -32 0 32 32 -32 -32 -32 32 0 129 0 64 32 -64 0 32 0 0 32 -32 -32 -32 32 128 0 64 0 0 33 33 0 32 32 64 32 -64 0 -225 0 -418 32 -97 32 -32 32 0 32 0 -32 -96 0 -65 32 -32 33 -128 32 -65 32 0 64 0 32 0 -32 -64 0 -32 0 32 0 0 -32 -64 -32 -65 -32 -353 0 -515 32 -386 64 -450 65 -161 64 -32 0 -32 0 -32 -32 0 -65 -32 0 32 -32 32 0 32 -32 0 -32 32 0 65 -64 96 -33 32 33 65 64 64 0 96 32 65 0 32 -32 0 -64 0 -33 -64 -32 -65 -32 -32 -32 32 32 65 32 128 65 161 64 161 0 418 -32 193 -65 257 -32 32 0 32 32 161 65 0 64 32 -64 0 -32 -32 0 0 32 -32 -32 -32 -33 -32 -32 -33 0 -32 -64 -96 -32 -32 -32 -65 0 0 -32 -64 0 -64 -65 -32 -32 -65 32 0 32 -32 -32 -32 0 -64 -96 -33 32 0 -32 -32 -65 -160 -96 0 -32 -33 32 -32 -32 0 -32 -32 0 -64 -32 -32 0 -65 32 0 -32 -32 -33 32 65 -64 32 -64 0 -32 -32 64 -32 32 -33 -32 -32 -97 0 -64 32 -32 33 -32 32 64 32 -32 64 0 32 32 0 -32 0 -32 0 -65 65 -32 0 -32 -33 32 -32 -32 -32 -32 0 0 32 0 -32 32 0 0 -32 64 -32 33 32 0 -32 32 0 0 -32 -32 0 -97 32 -96 0 -32 0 -65 0 -64 32 -64 0 -33 0 -32 32 -32 0 -64 32 -32 32 0 33 -32 0 -33 96 -64 32 -32 -32 64 -96 -32 -33 32 -32 -32 -32 -64 32 -65 32 -32 33 0 32 32 32 -32 96 -64 0 0 65 -96 64 -129 64 -32 0 0 32 -32 -32 0 32 -32 0 32 -32 -32 0 -65 32 32 0 0 33 -32 32 -32 -32 0 32 -64 0 32 -65 -32 0 -161 65 -32 32 -32 -32 0 -32 -33 32 0 -32 33 0 32 -97 64 -32 0 -32 -32 0 -64 -64 -33 0 0 -33 -32 65 -32 -32 -32 32 -32 32 0 32 -32 -32 -32 32 0 32 -33 0 -32 -32 32 -64 -32 -32 0 32 -64 0 0 32 0 -32 -32 32 0 32 -32 0 0 32 -32 -32 -65 64 0 -64 -32 0 0 -64 32 -32 32 -33 97 0 0 -64 32 32 32 -32 0 -32 32 -64 32 0 0 -33 -64 33 -32 -33 -64 33 0 32 0 -32 -32 -33 64 0 -32 0 0 -32 32 -32 32 -32 -32 0 0 -32 0 -32 -32 32 -32 -32 -33 0 -32 32 -32 -32 -32 0 32 32 -32 0 32 32 -64 0 32 64 0 -32 96 32 -64 32 -32 33 -32 0 0 32 -32 0 0 32 -33 -32 33 -32 -65 -65 -64 32 -32 -64 0 32 -32 0 0 65 -33 -33 0 33 -32 0 0 64 32 32 -32 0 0 32 -32 32 64 0 0 33 -64 0 -32 64 32 32 64 0 -64 32 -64 -64 -32 32 0 -32 0 -32 -32 0 0 32 -33 -32 -32 0 -32 64 -64 64 -32 -32 -32 0 -65 0 -96 64 -32 0 -65 33 -32 0 0 32 -32 32 -64 32 32 -64 0 -32 -32 0 -65 32 0 -32 0 32 0 -32 -32 0 -96 32 0 -32 -32 0 -33 64 -32 -32 0 32 -32 -32 -64 64 0 32 -32 0 0 32 -32 33 32 32 -32 0 -33 32 0 96 65 32 0 33 0 -33 -32 33 -33 0 0 32 0 32 33 0 -33 64 -32 0 0 32 32 33 -64 32 0 32 -32 0 32 0 32 0 -32 32 -32 0 0 64 32 32 32 33 -32 32 32 0 -32 32 32 0 32 0 33 0 0 -32 32 0 32 -32 32 0 -32 -33 32 0 0 -32 32 32 0 -32 32 0 32 -96 33 0 0 64 96 0 0 32 32 0 -32 32 0 65 -32 0 -32 0 0 32 -32 0 -33 0 33 0 0 -32 32 32 0 -32 32 0 0 -32 -32 0 0 -33 -65 65 0 -32 -64 -33 32 65 -32 32 32 -32 32 0 -64 64 -32 0 -32 32 0 -32 -32 32 32 0 -64 32 64 0 32 -32 0 32 32 0 32 -64 32 0 65 0 32 0 96 -32 -64 64 -64 161 -97 64 0 32 97 33 -32 -33 0 -32 32 0 32 -32 64 -128 97 -65 0 -32 96 -32 97 -32 0 -32 0 32 -33 32 -64 64 0 32 -32 65 32 32 97 32 32 -32 0 32 64 -32 97 64 -33 0 33 0 32 32 32 0 0 32 -32 33 -32 -65 -65 0 -32 0 -32 65 -32 32 -32 -32 -33 96 0 32 -96 129 -32 32 -32 0 -33 32 0 -96 -32 0 -32 0 0 -32 -32 0 -32 32 0 32 0 -97 -32 -32 -32 32 -33 33 -64 0 32 32 -64 -32 -32 -33 0 33 0 32 -32 0 -65 -32 -96 32 0 32 0 32 0 -32 -32 0 -32 32 32 32 -32 -32 -33 -32 -32 0 -64 -64 -97 -33 33 0 -33 -64 0 -32 -32 -64 0 -33 -96 -32 0 -32 -97 32 33 -32 -33 -32 0 -32 -64 -32 32 -32 -96 -33 -97 0 0 -96 -32 0 -32 -32 32 -32 0 -65zm15112 -3922l0 -33 32 0 0 33 -32 0zm-64 32l32 -32 32 32 -32 0 32 32 -64 0 0 -32zm-7042 3054l0 -32 0 32zm-1511 97l32 0 -32 0zm-2829 -161l0 32 0 -32zm-2701 418l0 32 32 0 -32 0 0 -32zm3858 -772l0 -32 0 32 32 0 0 32 -32 0 32 0 -32 0 0 -32zm-482 0l0 -32 32 0 -32 32zm3280 418l-33 0 0 -32 33 0 0 32zm-6688 354l0 32 0 -32zm96 643l-32 -32 -32 32 32 0 32 0zm-96 -289l32 0 -32 0zm546 450l0 -32 0 32zm-128 -900l32 0 -32 0 0 32 0 -32zm160 -161l33 0 32 0 0 32 -32 0 0 32 0 -32 0 32 -33 0 0 -32 33 0 0 -32 -33 0zm2894 -450l32 0 -32 0zm-3215 482l32 0 32 0 -32 0 0 32 -32 0 0 32 0 -32 0 -32zm5048 96l32 0 -32 0zm-2701 -193l0 33 0 -33 0 33 0 -33zm3923 0l0 -32 32 0 0 32 -32 0zm-3055 -64l0 -32 0 32zm3537 0l32 0 -32 0zm-6463 1608l0 -32 32 0 -32 0 0 32zm-450 -933l0 -32 32 0 -32 0 0 32zm3408 -707l0 32 0 -32zm161 -129l0 -32 32 0 0 32 -32 0zm3344 225l32 0 0 -32 0 32 -32 0zm-6881 708l0 -32 0 32 0 32 0 -32zm354 64l32 0 0 32 -32 0 0 32 -64 33 -33 32 -64 0 64 -32 65 -65 32 0 0 -32zm-129 -643l0 -32 32 0 0 -32 33 0 -33 32 0 32 -32 0zm5209 0l0 -32 0 32zm-5048 611l0 -32 32 0 0 32 -32 0zm6752 -643l32 0 0 32 0 -32 -32 0zm-3601 -386l32 0 -32 0zm-1029 289l0 -32 32 32 -32 0zm4405 129l32 0 0 32 -32 0 0 -32zm-6848 32l0 -32 32 0 0 32 0 -32 0 32 -32 0zm7266 -1479l0 -64 0 -32 32 0 -32 32 32 32 -32 32zm-7491 1897l32 -32 32 32 -64 65 0 -65zm3022 -739l32 -32 64 -33 33 65 -65 32 0 -32 -32 32 -32 -32zm547 0l0 -32 32 -33 32 -32 32 0 0 32 -32 33 -32 64 -32 -32zm3311 -708l0 32 0 33 32 -33 0 -32 -32 0zm-4791 1672l-32 0 32 -32 -32 -32 -64 32 32 -64 -32 -32 -64 0 -97 0 -64 32 32 32 -96 96 0 65 -65 0 33 -32 -65 0 0 -33 32 -32 33 -64 0 -32 -33 -32 -64 64 0 -64 -64 32 -32 -32 0 -32 64 -33 32 0 32 -32 32 0 33 -32 64 0 32 -32 -32 -32 32 -32 32 32 0 -32 0 -33 97 -64 -33 97 33 0 0 32 32 0 32 -65 32 0 -32 -32 96 0 0 -32 32 0 0 -64 -32 0 97 -32 0 -32 32 0 0 32 96 0 0 32 65 0 0 32 32 0 -32 0 -32 0 -65 0 0 32 32 0 33 -32 0 64 32 0 96 0 32 0 0 65 0 32 33 0 32 0 0 -32 32 0 0 -33 96 -32 32 32 -32 33 -64 32 32 32 -32 64 32 0 32 0 65 -64 0 32 32 64 96 0 -32 65 -64 0 -32 32 -65 0 32 -32 -32 -32 -32 -33 -96 33 -65 64 -32 -32 -32 0 -32 64 32 0 0 32 -64 32 0 -32 -32 -32 -97 32 -32 0 -64 0 -33 32z"/>
        <text class="capital" y="137500" x="146500">Rio de Janeiro</text>
    </g>
```

Comment: Hi Rene! Thank you so much for your help. It gave me some idea of what to do, but I`m struggling in the same step. When I open the SVG file, it shows de data of the drawing condensed in just a few <path> tags. So I cannot separate the area of the states to create for them a class and put them onto CSS modifications. Here is the SVG file for you to check? https://ufile.io/y15c73mb and thanks anyhow, you already helped

Comment: As I see it Renato, either use the current SVG and overlay HTML `<tags>` like @LaurentC showed you, or redo the SVG and include SVG `<text>`. A third option would be loading the SVG as an `<img>` and use `<map><area>` to create hotspots. All have their own quirks and will take time to complete. I personally would probably go for a new SVG and have everything inside one file (new layer in the orginal SVG and trace contours and add text or copy/paste parts of the original lines as new objects), but that's up to you to decide... And if you thinks it's worth it, accept one of the answers...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone!

I found the solution like this: I drawed the map on Inkscape and separated the neighborhoods on different layers. So when I saved it as SVG it had all the paths separated. That way I could manage to edit and customize them with no problem.

For anyone with a problem like this, Inkscape is the best tool I found for editing and customizing SVG. It gives you all the code almost ready and easy for edition.