# Angular transclusion without wrapping tag

Tags: angular, angular-template, transclusion

How can one make slot transclusion in Angular without including wrapping tag?

For example:

Here is template of component with selector `my-component`:

```
<div class="my-component">
   <p class="some sensitive css-classes">
       <ng-content select="sub-header"></ng-content>
   </p>

   <p class="more sensitive css-classes">
       <ng-content select="sub-footer"></ng-content>
   </p>
</div>
```

This was one of the components which filled in the template with data

```
<my-component>
    <sub-header>
        Very <strong>important</strong> text with tags.
    </sub-header>

    <sub-footer>
        More <em>important</em> text with tags.
    </sub-footer>
</my-component>
```

The transclusion result looks so:

```
<div class="my-component">
   <p class="some sensitive css-classes">
       <sub-header>
          Very <strong>important</strong> text with tags.
       </sub-header>
   </p>

   <p class="more sensitive css-classes">
       <sub-footer>
           More <em>important</em> text with tags.
       </sub-footer>
   </p>
</div>
```

This is not very useful, because of semantics and in case of very sensitive CSS-styles

How can I get transclusion which looks like this:

```
<div class="my-component">
   <p class="some sensitive css-classes">
       Very <strong>important</strong> text with tags.
   </p>

   <p class="more sensitive css-classes">
       More <em>important</em> text with tags.
   </p>
</div>
```

The main difference from other questions is the transclusion of dom.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove the host HTML element selectors created by angular component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34280475/remove-the-host-html-element-selectors-created-by-angular-component)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `ngProjectAs` angular attribute on `ng-container` tag

```
<my-component>
  <ng-container ngProjectAs="sub-header">
    Very 
    <strong>important</strong> text with tags.
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container ngProjectAs="sub-footer">
    More 
    <em>important</em> text with tags.
  </ng-container>
</my-component>
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ijggad?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts)**

For documentation take a look at https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/1683

Comment: It looks not very clean, but it works!!! If there comes no better solution, I will accept this as the answer!

Comment: where is this even documented!? :D

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Added :)

Comment: You will probably need to use `ng-container` or `ng-template`. ` https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/

Comment: Kinda dissapointing to see that there is no documentation about this, as there isnt a place designated for it (since already v2) https://github.com/angular/angular.io/pull/2851. For anyone looking for more info check https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/ng-content-the-hidden-docs-96a29d70d11b

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Thanks. That is a great article

Comment: Brilliant, I have been looking for ages how to do this.