# Render a nested component dynamically (created in the parent component) as a directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-components

Is it possible to render a nested component dynamically (created in the parent component) as a directive?

I know I can do something like this:

```html
    <svg>
      <svg:g skick-back-drop-item />
    </svg>
```

where "skick-back-drop-item" is the following component:

```js
    @Component({
    selector: '[skick-back-drop-item]',
    templateUrl: './back-drop-item.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./back-drop-item.component.scss'],
    })
    export class BackDropItemComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
```

But I would like to see if I can create/instantiate that child component in the parent component and then inject it into any DOM element as a directive, the DOM elements would be something like this:

```html
    <svg>
      <svg:g #svgContainer/>
    </svg>
```

I was creating the child component within the parent component dynamically using ComponentFactoryResolver and the ViewContainerRef from @angular/core

```js
     performFrame() {

      ....
     //Add nested component
      const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(
        BackDropItemComponent
      );
      const componentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);
      componentRef.instance.imagePath = objectUrl;
    }
  }
```

But that approach creates the following wrapper div container:

```html
    <div _nghost-hoc-c42="" skick-back-drop-item="" class="ng-star-inserted">
```

If the component is rendered as directive, only the content of the child component is rendered, which is what i need, because the child component contains SVG elements. If that wrapper is added, the SVG doesn't render because that weird div in the SVG tree.

Answer (score 1):

You may remove the host or turn it into a valid svg --> like here: [Remove the host HTML element selectors created by angular component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34280475/remove-the-host-html-element-selectors-created-by-angular-component)

Comment: One of the answers on that post could offer a solution to my problem, however this question is more focused on creating  and injecting a component as a directive in the DOM. I have up-voted your answer but i will wait to see if someones comes out with another approach to tackle the issue.